# When reinstalling a transmission what other components should be replaced?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, seal

2009 Kia Sedona (Base) automatic transmission.  that has a rebuilt transmission developed a huge fluid leak suddenly. All fluid gone in seconds. I've taken it out and found that The Tpump bushing wasn't installed correctly which caused it to (A.) Knock out the seal (B.) Become stuck on torque converter shaft and spin along with it effectively boring out some of the metal.

transmission is out.
And I have several questions

what's the best way to clean out the inside of the transmission to eliminate the metal ?

What is the best gasket maker for transmission specific gaskets?

What other components should I change? (Necessary)

What other components WOULD you change ? (Recommended)

There's minimal literature or videos on this, including the shotty KIA tech manuals which leave much to be desired.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> what's the best way to clean out the inside of the transmission to eliminate the metal ?

Without a complete teardown, clean up, and rebuild, there's just about no way to ensure you've cleaned up all the metal out of the transmission. That said, considering you lost all of the transmission fluid, I'd suggest nearly all of the metal has been flushed out or never entered the transmission in the first place. There is no guarantee here, though, so read my first statement if you want to be totally sure. Do remember, besides heat, contamination is pretty much the death knell of transmissions. I've heard rebuilders say, "Cleanliness is next to Godliness" when it comes to building a transmission which will last.

> What is the best gasket maker for transmission specific gaskets?

Done right, you really don't need any gasket maker. If you're dead set on using it, I ALWAYS prefer Permatex's *The Right Stuff*. It seals the first time, every time. You can even use it on wet/oily surfaces and it will still seal. A little expensive, but you get what you pay for.

> What other components should I change? (Necessary)

Filter from inside the transmission pan. Also, you want to clear the transmission cooler and lines. Anything which may be in there will go right back into the transmission and could cause issues. If you plan on reusing the torque converter, you need it have it cleaned out. This requires disassembly, cleaning, inspection, and reassembly.

> What other components WOULD you change ? (Recommended)

If you can afford it, cheap insurance would be to replace the torque converter to a new or a remanned one.